# zero height textarea is not zero pixels high

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make collapsible widgets in a side panel on my page. For the most part it works fine. I'm able to set the height of child div's to 0px with a transition, and they disappear.

However, I've found that a textarea will not collapse completely. When I set the height of the textarea to 0px it **seems** to transition like the other div's, but it still appears to occupy more space then 0px high.

The html is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="heading" onclick="toggleSiblings(this)">heading</div>
    <textarea class="collapsible" placeholder="type in here..."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="heading" onclick="toggleSiblings(this)">heading</div>
    <div class="collapsible"></div>
</div>
```

toggleSibblings() loops through all the siblings with a class of "collapsible" and toggles the "collapsed" class on them. The "collapsed" class just sets the height to 0px

Here's a jsfiddle to show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/447n50cy/

Can anyone tell my why the textarea is occupying the extra space?

Comment: Why not use `display: none` alongwith `height: 0`?

Comment: Then I don't get the transition. I was initially trying to set `display: none` with a `setTimeout()` so that the transition would be shown, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `float:left;` or `display:block;` along with transitioning to `padding:0;` will cause it to collapse. As an inline-block element it has issues collapsing properly.

Comment: If you can use jQuery I think functions like slideToggle() handle all the display/float/overflow/padding issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea have by default margin and padding:

You could reset the textarea:

```
textarea {
margin:0;
padding:0;
outline:0;
}
```

Add this to your fiddle. The problem is that you probably want some padding when people enter something in the textarea. You could easily use jQuery to add and remove classes.